# Find the remainder when $9^{16} - 5^{16}$ is divided by $14$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Tried a lot. Though unable to find starting point.

Comment: Hint: $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$

Answer (score 8):

Hint:

Since

$$9 \equiv -5 \pmod{14}$$

$$9^{16} - 5^{16} \equiv (-5)^{16} - 5^{16} \pmod{14}$$

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$
9^{16}-5^{16}=(9^8-5^8)(9^8+5^8)\tag{1}.
$$
By Euler's theorem,
$$
9^6\equiv 1\mod 14;\quad 5^6\equiv 1\mod 14 
$$
since $5$ and $9$ are coprime to $14$. Then
$$
9^8-5^8\equiv 9^2-5^2\equiv4(14)\equiv0\mod{14}
$$
and the result follows from (1).